# Using the same URL split traffic based on country?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, server, cdn

I have a website that operates in the UK, I wish to expand to the US using the same URL but with two different servers (one UK server and one US server, as the websites on each server will be completely different). The website is a wordpress marketplace hosted by a linux EC2.

How can I send users from the US to the US version of the site? can I also allow users to alternate between to the two versions? (incase someone from the US wishes to see the UK version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with Route53 and geo routing:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html

**More details:**
You would setup your website / service in the 2 different locations, using 2 different stacks. You need a domain that you've registered and you need Route53 to manage that domain.

You need to create a record set that points your domain based on location. Read through: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-location
You need to select the geolocation routing and point the 2 regions to each stack. You also need to set a fallback in case you don't fall in any of the regions.

Also see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/route-53-domain-reg-geo-route-price-drop/

Comment: thankyou for your response, I really appreciate it. Do you mind going into more detail?

Comment: added more details. you need to try it. it's going to be funny at first if you haven't worked with route53 but it's an easy [enough] learning curve.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I am going to transfer my domain to amazon Route 53, then create a record set with a routing policy and set the location to the US. I will update my comment once I have accomplished this with a clear guide for anyone else wanting to do this.

Comment: how can I now allow users to alternate between to the two servers? (i.e. have a button on the site to switch the server to the U.S./U.K. version)

Comment: a very simple way of accomplishing this is to redirect them to the other website when they click the switch button.

Comment: how can I do this? use a link to the ip address of the other server? I have a feeling if I do that and the user clicks on any other links on the site they will be re-routed back to the site within their country (as the links contain the URL), also if I use this ip method the URL show the IP address and not the domain

Comment: could this be achieved using a cookie?

Comment: the long answer is yes. you could deploy the static content of your website via something like cloud front and have a cookie control the backend part (which backend you talk to). more work though

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I would love to avoid that if possible, it will make this job much much larger. Is there any way to communicate with route 53 to tell it which server to send users to?

Comment: or a way to bypass route 53 if the user has a cookie?

Comment: you can serve your website from cloudfront and detect the backend region if no cookie, set the cookie once you know the backend.

Comment: I will look into cloudfront now, I have never used it but are you saying have the domain point to a server which sets a location cookie? then once the user has a cookie I can use it to route the requests to either of the servers? kind of like a load balancer but based on location

Comment: from the sounds of it there isn't really a simple way to do this, however I feel there must be something out there that does this