# split my wordpress site into a UK and US version?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a website that operates in the UK, and I wish to expand to the US using the same URL but with two different versions of the site. The website is a wordpress marketplace hosted by a linux EC2.

I would ideally like to host the two websites on two different servers in each corresponding region using the same URL. Doing this will allow me to duplicate the UK version of the site (backup and launch a copy on a server in the US region), then I can simply remove all the users and products and start again in the US.

How can I send users from the US to the US version of the site and also allow users to alternate between to the two versions? (incase someone from the US wishes to see the UK version)

so far I have researched using Amazons Route53 geo routing, this allows me to route traffic to the different servers based on location however I could not then figure out how to allow the users to switch between regions as all IP requests are automatically routed.

any siggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you might need to use either subdomains e.g `us.example.com` & `uk.example.com` or directories e.g `example.com/usa/` & `example.com/uk/`. Also, isn't this question exactly the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955491/using-the-same-url-split-traffic-based-on-country ?

Comment: thank you for your response, its similar, I wished to clarify exactly what I was aiming for